# python creating string from yaml vars

Tags: python

i have the following yaml file:

```
rule_groups:
  - name: "APPSTREAM"
    allowed-domains:
     - ".github.com"
     - ".google.com"
    source: "10.143.80.0/24"

  - name: "TEST"
    allowed-domains:
     - ".microsoft.com"
     - ".amazonaws.com"
    source: "10.143.70.0/24"
```

i am calling inside a python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml

with open('settings.yaml', 'rb') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
core_config = config['rule_groups']

for workload in core_config:
  print(workload)


{'name': 'APPSTREAM', 'allowed-domains': ['.github.com', '.google.com'], 'source': '10.143.80.0/24'}
{'name': 'TEST', 'allowed-domains': ['.microsoft.com', '.amazonaws.com'], 'source': '10.143.70.0/24'}
```

i am trying to create a dynamic string for every `name` ,  `allowed-domains` and `sid` and write the outpot into a file , as following:

```
$APPSTREAM ,.google.com, sid:1
$APPSTREAM ,.github.com, sid:2
$TEST, .microsoft.com, sid:3
$TEST, .amazonaws.com,sid:4
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml
with open('settings.yaml', 'rb') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
core_config = config['rule_groups']

i = 0

for workload in core_config:
  for domain in (workload['allowed-domains']):
    i = i+1
    print(f"${workload['name']},'{domain}',sid:{i}")
```

Comment: `for i, domain  in enumerate(workload['allowed-domains']):` [...] `sid:{i+1}` would be more pythonic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).